# Gurobipy issue: fails to write IIS to .ilp file

Tags: python, gurobi

We are using `Gurobipy` (from its Gurobi cloud offering). We are leveraing its [IIS feature](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_computeiis.html#pythonmethod:Model.computeIIS)  to handle the infeasibility debugging.

But `Gurobipy` **fails to write the IIS to `.ilp` file** (i.e. generates a completely empty file).

Below is the minimal reproducible code:

*main.py*

```py
import gurobipy

my_model = gurobipy.read("my_problem.lp", conf_env())  
# Note: conf_env() is custom func to set secret key

my_model.optimize()
my_model.computeIIS()         
my_model.write('my_iis.ilp')   # Generates an empty file: my_iis.ilp
```

*my_problem.lp*

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name:

Minimize
 obj: x1 + x2
Subject To
 c1: - x1 <= -20
 c2: - x2 <= -20
 c3: - x1 <= -60
 c4: - x2 <= -60
 c5: x1 + x2 <= 110
Bounds
      x1 Free
      x2 Free
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine (both using the Gurobi Cloud and a local optimization) your code works fine and generates this ILP file:

```
Minimize
 
Subject To
 c3: - x1 <= -60
 c4: - x2 <= -60
 c5: x1 + x2 <= 110
Bounds
 x1 free
 x2 free
End
```

This is the corresponding output:

```
Using license file C:\gurobi\gurobi.lic
Read LP format model from file inf.lp
Reading time = 0.00 seconds
obj: 5 rows, 2 columns, 6 nonzeros
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.2 build v9.1.2rc0 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 5 rows, 2 columns and 6 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xd8caa76c
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range        [2e+01, 1e+02]
Presolve removed 4 rows and 2 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s

Solved in 0 iterations and 0.00 seconds
Infeasible or unbounded model
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0      handle free variables                          0s

IIS computed: 3 constraints and 0 bounds
IIS runtime: 0.00 seconds
```

There must be something wrong with your setup since the code and the model file are correct. You should check the solver output for any clues.

**EDIT:**

Updating Gurobi fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, ideally it should have worked. Given it also correctly populated `IISCONSTR`, `IISQCONSTR`, `IISGENCONSTR`, `IISSOS`, `IISLB`, `IISUB`.

Comment: Moreover, the contemporary `my_model.write('my_prob.lp')` and `my_model.write('my_sol.sol')` are working perfectly fine.

Comment: Surprisingly, only this `.ilp` is malfunctioning.

Comment: Interesting! Are you using the latest version of Gurobi? Maybe there has been an issue in an older version?

Comment: Not the latest, but very recent, We are using Gurobi's version 9.0.0.

Comment: Switching to new Gurobi would be a big organizational level change, Is there  any way to fix the existing version?

Comment: At the very least, I'd try using version 9.0.3 - the latest bugfix version of 9.0. You just need to replace the library file.

Comment: Thanks! I just re-installed Gurobipy's version 9.0.3 and it works fine now.

Comment: If I may ask - Does this also requires to re-purchase Gurobi's license, since earlier we had purchased license for version 9.0.0?

Comment: Most Gurobi licenses are valid for a certain time frame and only restrict to a certain major version - that would be 9 for current licenses. So you should not have any issues using 9.1.2.

Comment: For licensing questions, it's generally best to go to support.gurobi.com.

Comment: Then please mark this question as solved. I added the fix to my answer.